# Characteristic X-Rays During K-Electron Capture

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radioactivity, x-rays

We know that when an electron is knocked from the innermost shell of an atom (K - shell), a vacancy is created in the K - Shell. This vacancy in the K - Shell is by an electron falling from an upper shell (usually L-Shell or M-Shell) producing photons due to falling of electron from an upper to a lower orbit. These are called Characteristic X-Rays.

---

> MY QUESTION:
>
> During  Electron Capture (or K - Capture) type of β-decay, the nucleus
> absorbs an inner atomic electron hence converting the nuclear proton
> to a neutron and emitting an electron neutrino according to the
> following equation:
>
> $\hspace{6cm}$[image: reaction equation]
>
> My question is that when an electron is absorbed by the nucleus it
> automatically creates a vacancy in its shell, which needs to be
> filled. Hence does an electron from an upper shell fill the vacancy
> and emit characteristic X-Rays (and hence energy in addition to decay
> energy) or is the complete energy released only in the form of
> energy of the neutrino ?

Comment: Characteristic X-rays are emitted when the electron from the upper shell makes a transition to the inner shell and fills the hole. The neutrino is emitted in the process of proton conversion.

Comment: it is a bit tricky question because the nucleus therefore the atom itself changes in such a process, say N turns to C. So in principle all energy levels should change after such a process. I hope someone can answer this question.

Comment: X-rays are common efter a change of Z-number of the nucleus, but especially so for electron capture. For example Fe-55, where EC is followed in 25 % of cases by  manganese K$\alpha$ emission. http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=260055

Answer (score 2):

Yes, electron capture can be followed by the emission of a characteristic X-ray. This was first observed by Alvarez [1] (not using the famous bubble chamber he got the Nobel prize for!). Alternatively, an outer electron can be ejected (Auger effect). A thorough review of all theoretical and experimental aspects can be found in [2].

[1] Luis W. Alvarez. Nuclear K electron capture. Phys. Rev., 52:134–135, Jul 1937

[2] W. Bambynek, H. Behrens, M. H. Chen, B. Crasemann, M. L. Fitzpatrick, K. W. D. Ledingham, H. Genz, M. Mutterer, and R. L. Intemann. Orbital electron capture by the nucleus. Rev. Mod. Phys., 49:77–221, Jan 1977.